# What is meant by pre-OS communication?

Tags: operating-system, serial-communication, ipmi

While reading about serial over LAN, I came across this words.

*"This can be used to enable asynchronous serial based OS and pre-OS communication over a connection to the Soc"*

In the above sentence what is meant by "asynchronous serial based OS" and "pre-OS communication"

Comment: Please provide the context/source alongwith the question.

Comment: I suspect that condusing and/or missing punctuation is causing confusion.  The two possibilites are 'asynchronous serial based communication supported by the OS' and 'asynchronous serial based communication that can boot an OS'.